# Marathon kills container when requests increase

Tags: mesos, marathon

I deploy Docker containers on Mesos(0.21) and Marathon(0.7.6) on Google Cloud Engine.
I use JMeter to test a REST service that run on Marathon. When the concurrent requests are less than 10, it works normal, but when the concurrent requests are over 50, the container is killed and Mesos start another container. I increase RAM, CPU but it still happens.
This is log in /var/log/mesos/

`E0116 09:33:31.554816 19298 slave.cpp:2344] Failed to update resources for container 10e47946-4c54-4d64-9276-0ce94af31d44 of executor dev_service.2e25332d-964f-11e4-9004-42010af05efe running task dev_service.2e25332d-964f-11e4-9004-42010af05efe on status update for terminal task, destroying container: Failed to determine cgroup for the 'cpu' subsystem: Failed to read /proc/612/cgroup: Failed to open file '/proc/612/cgroup': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing is actually another symptom, not the root cause of the issue. There's a good explanation/discussion in this Apache Jira bug report:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1837

Basically, your container is crashing for one reason or another and the /proc/pid#/ directory is getting cleared without Mesos being aware, so it throws the error message you found when it goes to check that /proc directory.

Try setting your allocated CPU higher in the JSON file describing your task.